# Parameter passing on Salesforce1 Publisher Action

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, custom-actions

I have a visualforce page that is used as a custom publisher action.
How can I pass parameters to this visualforce page when calling the page from the publisher action?

Any ideas on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: Where would your parameters be coming from in this case? I don't think it is possible, but I'm curious if you could query for the information you need based on a the context of the record you came from (if this isn't a global action).

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between global (publisher) actions and object-specific custom actions.

When you create a custom action on a specific object, the visualforce page linked to that custom action should be built using the standard controller of that type of object.
When you do, then offcourse you have all access to that object's information.

From the docs (Using Visualforce Pages as Custom Actions):
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/index_Left.htm#CSHID=vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fvf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Also from the docs (Standard Controllers):
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_std.htm

Comment: Do you found a valid solution to pass parameters on object specific publisher actions? If you could give me some informations how you potentially solved your issue, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look also to this presentation, might be is algo helpful. A good summary and demos about what can we do with Chatter Publisher Actions ( Micro Moments) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEBJE3qwtXQ